# adding private key to ssh agent

Tags: linux, ssh

I was referring to http://www.mtu.net/~engstrom/ssh-agent.php

My public key is listed under ~/.ssh/authorized_keys at remote1. During SSH login connect,
it's working fine(loaded my private key under connection-Auth), it asked for passphrase which I provided then login is successful.
But when switching between servers like from remote2, do SSH remote1, it would ask for a password. Trying to set up SSH agent forwarding according to that site but was to no avail...ssh-add never prompts me for private-key-passphrase or was it wrong what i was doing trying to follow the process described?

I basically did 
$ eval `ssh-agent`
$ ssh-add (some do ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa--> wonder wat id_rsa is referring to as I only have the auth_keys file under .ssh)

Saw some resources described to do chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys, but not sure if that's applicable to my case.

Comment: This is offtopic here as it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: I guess I sort of sort it out with the Putty's Pageant - Add keys(add private key and key in passphrase) then connect to the saved remote session. as when I did ssh-add -L/-l something is there.
just that it still asks for password when i connect to it from other remote server to it

Comment: Adding -A solved the password part

Answer (score 5):

ssh-agent wrap another command, you can for example wrap a shell

```
ssh-agent bash
```

Then, in that shell, you need to add your private key, and type your passphrase :

```
ssh-add /path/to/your/private/key # (by default : ~/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

Then, when you use ssh to connect, add the -A option :

```
ssh -A user@remote1
```

That's it, your key is forwarded, you can see it if you type (on remote1) :

```
ssh-add -L
```

You can now connect to your remote2, using that private key.

Be careful when you use ssh forwarding. Anyone with root access on remote1 could use your identity to connect on remote2 while you are connected.

Comment: If you don't know the path to your private key, try to connect to your remote1, it should ask you the passphrase of your key, and print the path of this key.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that ~/.ssh/authorized_keys must always be chmod 600.  This is a sensitive file that must be protected.

Comment: If I change permission for that file to chmod 600, would that affect other people access?